# Getting Time limit exceeded error in java

Tags: java, optimization

```
class Check {
    static void countOddEven(int a[], int n) {

        int countEven = 0, countOdd = 0;
        for (int item : a) {
            if (item % 2 == 0) {
                countEven++;
            }
        }

        countOdd = n - countEven;

        System.out.println(countOdd + " " + countEven);

    }
}
```

Code is to calculate even and odd numbers in an array. Please help to optimise the code.

Comment: I don't think any substantial optimization is possible in this metod in isolation. You may try giving more context.

Comment: Use *Bitwise AND* operator instead of *Modulo* (`item & 1 == 0`). Be aware that this method is only true when `item` is a positive number

Comment: @Ammar that's not any faster. Maybe that trick worked on a commodore 64 or an i286, but in this modern age? Nope.

Comment: Code was not formatted properly.

Answer (score 2):

You’re code is not correct.

If you were meant to count the even and odd numbers in `a`, then you are counting the even numbers correctly. If `n` is not equal to the length of `a`, then your calculation of the count of odd numbers is incorrect.

If on the other hand — and I’m just guessing — you were meant to count the even and odd numbers among the first `n` elements, then you are counting the even numbers incorrectly since you are iterating over all of `a`. Also in this case, if `n` is much smaller than the length of `a`, there is an optimization in only iterating over the first `n` elements as you should.

Finally you may try the following version. I doubt that it buys you anything, but I am leaving the measurements to you.

```
    int countOdd = 0;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < n; ix++) {
        countOdd += a[ix] & 1;
    }

    int countEven = n - countOdd;
```

The trick is: `a[ix] & 1` gives you the last bit of `a[ix]`. This is 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers (positive or negative). So we are really adding a 1 for each odd number.

Comment: n is the length of a itself. Btw the issue was with the code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion 

Comment: Sure, NP. I didn’t get it, though, sorry. Improper formatting shouldn’t cause code to take long time? And as an aside, prefer not to pass the length of the array as a separate argument. The method can and should just use `a.length`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try running code with for loop instead of for each loop

Because ,

When accessing arrays, at least with primitive data **for loop** is dramatically faster.
however
When accessing collections, a **foreach** is significantly faster than the basic for loop’s array access.

but if you are getting some another errors , so might have done something wrong while calling the method (make sure n=length of your array)

here is the whole code with main method.

```
class Check{
    static void countOddEven(int a[], int n){

        int countEven=0,countOdd=0;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      if(a[i]%2==0)
     {
         countEven++;
     }

     countOdd=n-countEven;

    System.out.println(countOdd+" "+countEven);

    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        int a[]={2,3,4,5,6};
        int n = 5;

        countOddEven(a,n);

    }
}
```